# docusign :: how to void a "in-progress" envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

Please help.

I have been trying to void a "in-progress" envelope with one signature out of three signatures, but I receive this error msg. 
I follow the instruction from : http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Void%20Envelope.htm.

Also looked at the previous question asked, but that didn't help me at all.

**Error**
The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Invalid value for 'status' in envelope definition. Only 'sent' or 'created' (default) are allowed.

URL: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/35****/envelopes/f466ad3f-d391-****--*********

PARAMS: {"status":"voided","voidedReason":"Voided due to late change request."}
INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're doing a `PUT` request and not a `POST`?

Just tested and was able to void 3 envelopes just fine with no problems, using the same request body as you've listed.  Not sure what language you're using, but here's a full working PHP program that creates and sends an envelope so that's in-process, then it immediately voids it.

To run this program:

1. Save code as local file, say "test.php".
2. Enter credentials at top (email, pwd, integrator key, name)
3. Copy a test PDF document to same directory, rename to "document.pdf"
4. run `php test.php` on command line

Here's the code, don't forget to replace creds...

```
<?php

    // Input your info here:
    $integratorKey = '***';
    $email = '***';
    $password = '***';
    $name = '***';

    // construct the authentication header:
    $header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
    $baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
    curl_close($curl);

    //--- display results
    echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 2 - Create an envelope with one recipient, one tab, and one document and send
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $data = array (
            "emailBlurb" => "Custom PHP script",
            "emailSubject" => "Radio Buttons Testing",
            "status" => "sent",
            "documents" => array(array( "documentId" => "1", "name" => "document.pdf")),
            "recipients" => array( "signers" => array(
                    array( "email" => $email,
                            "name" => "$name",
                            "recipientId" => "1",
                            "clientUserId" => "1001",
                            "tabs" => array(
                                    "signHereTabs" => array(
                                        array(
                                            "xPosition" => "100",
                                            "yPosition" => "200",
                                            "documentId" => "1",
                                            "pageNumber" => "1"
                                         )
                                    ),
                                    "radioGroupTabs" => array(
                                        array (
                                            "documentId" => "1",                                        
                                            "groupName" => "RadioGroup1",
                                            "radios" => array (
                                                array(
                                                    "pageNumber" => "1",
                                                    "selected" => "false",
                                                    //"value" => "X",
                                                    "xPosition" => "300",
                                                    "yPosition" => "75"
                                                    ),
                                                array(
                                                    "pageNumber" => "1",
                                                    "selected" => "false",
                                                    "xPosition" => "350",
                                                    "yPosition" => "75"
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                        )
                ) 
        );

    $data_string = json_encode($data);  

    $file_contents = file_get_contents("document.pdf");

    $requestBody = "\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."--myboundary\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."$data_string\r\n"
    ."--myboundary\r\n"
    ."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\”document.pdf\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."$file_contents\r\n"
    ."--myboundary--\r\n"
    ."\r\n";

    // *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint
    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
        print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

    curl_close($curl);

    //--- display results
    echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n"; 

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 3 - Get the Embedded Singing View 
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
    $data = array("status" => "voided", "voidedReason" => "test");
    $data_string = json_encode($data);    

    echo "Attempting to void envelope $envelopeId\nVoid request body is:  $data_string\n";

    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes/$envelopeId" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
        print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

    echo "Done.\n";
    curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but now I am getting this msg The request body is missing or improperly formatted.

URL: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/353***/envelopes/3f8fbe05-63f9-418a-******

PARAMS: {"status":"voided","voidedReason":"test"}
INVALID_REQUEST_BODY

Comment: What language are you using, and how are you forming your JSON?  Just hard-coding into a string?

Comment: There must be something else wrong with your request, I just tested three times and was able to create a new envelope, send it, and void the envelope with no problems each time.  I'll attach a full working PHP program that does this.  YOu need to show your relevant code...

Comment: I was having the exact same problem. I was trying to submit a void over the API and was getting, "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER; The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Invalid value for 'status' in envelope definition.  Only 'sent' or 'created' (default) are allowed." I reviewed my cURL request and added the following line:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');

After this, voids worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting, I assume that's the same issue the person who posted this question was running into and they just never accepted as an answer...